# How can I increase the font and sidebar size?

Tags: beamer, colorbox, sidebar

I would like to add increase the size of the sidebar to 2.5cm and increase the size of the text proportionally.

At the bottom I would like to create a box taking the entire length of the frame. The part immediately below the sidebar must be the same color (black) and with a white font. The rest of the box must be white (like the frame's bg) and contain the author's name, title of the work, date and current slide. How can I do this?

**The image represents what I want to do (put information in a lower bar - author, date and frame).**

```
    \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[abnt-emphasize=bf,alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,url}
\usepackage{color}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[square]


\graphicspath{{./Figuras/}} 
\usecolortheme{dove}
\useoutertheme[left, height=0pt]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=white}


%=========================================================================
\title[]{Título da Apresentação}
\author[]{Ezequiel Contê}
\institute[UFLA]{\\ Universidade AAB}
\date[2020]{25 de Novembro de 2020}

%=========================================================================
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Sumário}
    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections]
\end{frame}

%=========================================================================
%=========================================================================
\section{Introdução}

\subsection{Produção e análise de sementes}
\begin{frame}{Título}
    Texto A
\end{frame}

\subsection{Processamento de imagens}
\begin{frame}{Título}
    Texto B
\end{frame}

\subsection{Redes Neurais e máquinas de comitês}
\begin{frame}{Título}
    Texto C
\end{frame}

\subsection{Métricas de avaliação}
\begin{frame}{Título}
    Texto D
\end{frame}
%=========================================================================
%=========================================================================
\section{Materiais e métodos}
\begin{frame}{Título}
    Texto E
\end{frame}
%=========================================================================
%=========================================================================
\section{Resultados e discussões}
\begin{frame}{Título}
    Texto F
\end{frame}

%=========================================================================
%=========================================================================
\section{Conclusões}
\begin{frame}{Título}
    Texto G
\end{frame}
%=========================================================================
%=========================================================================

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the bottom bar with the information using the following code.

```
\setbeamercolor{coloredbox1}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{coloredbox2}{fg=black,bg=white}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2355\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{coloredbox1}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.65\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{coloredbox2}%
            \usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1145\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{coloredbox2}%
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

It's all solved.

Answer (score 0):

About increasing the dimensions of the sidebar and the font size, the solution is this:

```
\useoutertheme[left, height=0pt, width=4cm]{sidebar} 
\setbeamerfont{sidebar}{size=\scriptsize} 
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\small}
```

Credits to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

I still need to put the bottom bar with the information (author, date, frame...).